# create array from mysql

Tags: php, arrays

I have column in mysql where are some words.
For example word,dog,cat,tree..

Is it possible to create php array like this?

```
$array=array("word","dog","cat","tree");
```

Comment: You have just created an array ....

Comment: Come on, he means: create an array holding content from mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use php `explode()` function

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
or 
$row=$pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$newarray=explode(",",$row["data"]);
```

Comment: If you can avoid it, please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @vascowhite see the edited answer...and stop copying others comment and downvoting

Comment: @vascowhite for OP. May be OP is not familiar with `PDO`.

Comment: So, he can learn. Why bother with mysql_* functions at all when PDO is no harder to learn and so much safer?

Comment: @vascowhite I think you should say this to OP. Not to me. i have given my answer about exploding the array and `explode` function do not require how we are connecting to database?

Comment: But the OP never mentioned mysql_* functions, that is why I aimed the comments at you as you introduced them into the thread. He appears to be a beginner (judging by the question) who should definitely be going straight to PDO without bothering with mysql_*.

Comment: @vascowhite That's right ..But the method you are using like down voting and copying other's comment is wrong.You can also suggest OP for that

Comment: Wrong? How? I am allowed to down vote an answer that I consider to be flawed in some way. That is exactly what down votes are for.

Comment: @vascowhite If you really cares what OP should learn `PDO` or `mysql` ? than you should suggest this to OP instead of me.

Answer (score 3):

You mean you want to split them by commas? Use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode):

```
$items = explode(',', $columnValue);
```